# Spark to SparkSQL equivqlent syntax

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this two line in spark, I want to get the equivalent in SparkSQL (im working with python env)

```
df = spark_df.filter(col["col_name".lower()].rlike("[0-9]{9}$")).count()

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn(columnname, F.to_date(F.col((columnname, ),"yyyyMMdd"))
```

Answer (score 1):

For spark sql first convert dataframe to temp view then run sql.

**`Example:`**

```
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
df=spark.sql("""select count(*) from tmp where lower(col_name) rlike("[0-9]{9}$") """).collect()[0][0]    

spark_df = spark.sql("""select *, to_date(columnname,"yyyyMMdd") columnname from tmp """)
```

Comment: what about the equivalent with SelectExpr ? sorry im newbie ..

Comment: Please close this question as accepted and open as new question for `selectExpr` equivalent syntax.

Comment: i opened a new thread here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170515/what-is-the-pyspark-selectexpr-equivalent-of-this-code